# Stable Equilibrium points for 2d Potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, equilibrium

> Consider a Lagrangian of the system $$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)+2ln|x-y|.$$

Basically I know how to solve for 1d potential and to find stable equilibrium points. But how to appr0ach for this kind of potential where the potential is not function of x only but y also. How do we basically find stable equilibrium points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points of stable equilibrium occur where the potential is at a minimum. Minimising a function of two variables is a standard undergraduate task. You can find out a lot about it online, for example here: [How can we minimize a function of two variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2058469/448779) or [here](https://www.themathdoctors.org/minimizing-a-function-of-two-variables-multiple-methods/).

A more "physical" way of finding out these points is to realise the following: the points of equilibrium occur when the force on the particle is zero. In other words, a necessary condition for a point $(x,y)$ to be an equilibrium is that the force $\mathbf{F}(x,y) = 0$. Of course, the force can be obtained from the potential $V(x,y)$ using the formula $\mathbf{F}(x,y)= -\nabla V(x,y)$. Therefore, the points of equilibrium occur when:

$$\mathbf{F}(x,y)= -\nabla V(x,y) = 0.$$

Of course, not *all* points at which the above condition hold are *stable* equilibria: some may be unstable, and some may be saddle points. Therefore, you will need to look at the second-order derivatives to know whether the equilibrium is stable or not, as is explained in the links mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks @Philip i got it. And truly speaking i wan never been taught in my grad and post grad also.

Comment: i have just one last doubt. I found the equilibrium points to be (1,1) and (1,-1). But i think (1,1) should be discarded as it makes the condition approaching to infinity when (x,y)=(1,1). Can you verify it.